# How to show a default text '---' instead of blanks in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report in which I need to show a default text '---' wherever there are blank values for a field called ExpectedInDate.I am trying to achieve this using this formula:

```
IF isnull({DamageRepairEntry.ExpectedInDate}) THEN 
"N/A"
```

But there are a few issues, firstly I am confused as to where this formula should be written, secondly wherever I try to write this formula, I get an error :"The result of the formula should be a Boolean".Kindly help me with this, also forgive me if this seems like a silly question.

Comment: Where did you write this formula?

Comment: I tried doing this in Suppress formula for the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suppress formula only dictates whether the field displays on the report or not, which is why it must evaluate to a boolean value (`true` to suppress, `false` to display). Instead, you need to create a new standalone formula:

```
if isnull({DamageRepairEntry.ExpectedInDate}) then "--"
 else totext({DamageRepairEntry.ExpectedInDate})
```

Then place this new standalone formula object in your report instead of the `ExpectedInDate` database field.

Comment: I am getting an error : "A string is required here"

Comment: It has finally worked for me @Ryan, but I have changed the formula given by you in order to tackle the error that I mentioned above.

Comment: the updated formula is                                        if isnull({DamageRepairEntry.ExpectedInDate}) then "--" 
else
ToText({DamageRepairEntry.ExpectedInDate})

Comment: @Ryan, you need to convert `{DamageRepairEntry.ExpectedInDate}` to a string: `ToText( {DamageRepairEntry.ExpectedInDate} )`.